# Can a complex function be holomorphic at a point whose limit approaches infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex function, $z_0 \in \Omega$.  If $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h} = \infty$, is $f$ considered holomorphic at $z_0$?  I would think so, since via the Riemann sphere we have $\infty$ represented as a single point, which tells us that the limit indeed exists.  Is this correct intuition?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m43s12/notes/class11.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,
it would not be considered as holomorphic there,

$lim_{h→0}\frac{f(z_0+h)−f(z_0)}{h}=∞$ means that $z_0$ is a pole for $f$ and therefore it is not Holomorphic, it might be [Meromorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) there,

The Riemann sphere is defined in the extended complex plane - $\Bbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$

So you might think of it as holomorphic at it, 
Yet it would not stand for any theorem regarding Holomorphic functions.